# dotnet build command ignore .editorconfig

Tags: c#, .net-core, editorconfig

### System

- Visual Studio 2019 16.4.0
- .NET Core 2.2
- Windows 10

### Scenario

The NuGet package [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/) Visual Studio can perform code analysis of managed code.

Each diagnostic or rule has a default severity and suppression state that can be overwritten for your project.

There are multiple modes for [configure rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019)

I have used the `.editorconfig` mode and on Visual Studio IDE when building or editing it working properly.

Unfortunately when I build the project from the command line

```bsh
dotnet build
```

the `.editoconfig` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/33558), it looks like the language rules / analysis features will not currently trigger failures from running a command line build.

If you want the build tooling or a CI environment to recognize the `.editorconfig` ruleset, **you'll need to ensure that you are running Visual Studio 2019 running Version 16.3 or higher** [as mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#set-rule-severity-in-an-editorconfig-file).

Comment: I suppressed a rule: in the VS2019 it work but when I run `dotnet build` the suppressed rule is showed again

Comment: Was your expectation that it should cause a build failure (given that you indicated that it should be suppressed but the build didn't acknowledge the suppression)? If that's the case, that use case isn't currently supported (per the open issue I linked to).

If you are certain you are running 16.3 or higher of Visual Studio 2019, the build tooling _should_ recognize the `editorconfig` but it will still not cause failures and be at feature parity with the IDE yet.

Comment: VS2019 version 16.4.0

Comment: That's curious. It's possible there's still some issues since the tooling around `editorconfig` from the command line still seems to be in flux. You may consider trying the `dotnet-format` tool (https://github.com/dotnet/format/) that was recently recently and supposedly focuses on reading from `editorconfig` files.

Comment: I have the same issue, from VisualStudio 2019 th .editorconfig is respected (i have my rules set), but when CLI building the file is totally ignored. Can we specify to `dotnet build` anyhow the editorconfig file?

Comment: The tool `dotnet-format` is since .net6 part of the sdk and then spelt `dotnet format` (without dash). This tool respect .editorconfig, but does still not break the build `dotnet build`